# Android Animation when close Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I searched around but to no avail, I would like to know how I can create the animation same as that used by Chrome when you click "New Tab", it seems like a fan ... something like:

[image]

Comment: Is that for the exiting activity or entering activity?

Comment: I want to try this animation to close the activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are two parts to this animation. The translation and the rotation.

It looks like there is no x translation, so we'll only need to worry about a y translation, a positive one to be exact.

The rotation seems to be about 45 degrees to the right.

So let's define our xml animation file under "red/anim/" with the file name "so_exmaple_anim.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="100">

    <translate 
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="25%" />

    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="45" />
</set>
```

And then in your `Activity` right after executing the command to switch to another `Activity` use `Activity.overridePendingTransition()` with your anim file.

Comment: the XML has this error:`The value of attribute "android:toYDelta" associated with an element type "translate" must not contain the '<' character.`

Comment: I forgot the second `"` around the `"25%"`. I just fixed it.